# Center text and readjust to different screen sizes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

In my application I have a text, and I want to center it and I also want the text to fit the different screen sizes (desktop, tablet, smartphone), but also want on PC, when resizing the application window the text is adapt automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you set horizontal and vertical alignment on the textblock, it should be centered.

If you also want the text's size to adapt, put the textblock in a viewbox. (it's the lazy way)

The most elegant solution would be to create different views for desktop and mobile (using DeviceFamily-Desktop / DeviceFamily-Mobile notation). This way you could customize each one to the last bit

Comment: Or you can simply use `VisualState`s with `AdaptiveTrigger`s to make your UI responsive instead of creating new view for each device. But just for centering `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` are fine.